# Checking input for the whole exact string in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, input

So I'm creating a simple program to check the input for words contained in the list. I have something like this...

```
def function():
    list = ["hell", "yeah"]
    check_input = input("Sentence to check: ")
    check_input.split()
    check = any(item in check_input for item in list)
        if check is True:
            print("List word found!")
        else:
            print("Clean!")
```

The problem is I want it to check the input for the exact same string from the list. Not if the input contains just a part of it.

Basically: I want it so if the user types "hello world" into the input, check would return as false and print clean because **"hello"** isn't **"hell"**.

I guess I need to use something different than **any()** function, but I can't come up with anything that would solve this.
Any ideas?

Comment: You forgot to assign `check_input.split()`. Do `check_input = check_input.split()`. This seems to be just a typo, so I'm voting to close the question, but LMK if not and I can go into detail.

Comment: BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name cause it shadows the builtin `list`. If I were you, I'd call it `words` instead.

Comment: Sure, in my original code I called it different, I just wanted to simplify it here. And btw you're right, I've corrected it and it's working. Wow, I really wrote my first question here just because of a really stupid typo.. :DDD Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is slightly wrong due to which it is not working correctly.
Replace `check_input.split()` with `check_input=check_input.split()`

Or use `check_input = input("Sentence to check: ").split()`